# launch hidden app when secret code is dialed

Tags: android, service, broadcast, receiver

my requirement is to launch an hidden app when a secret code is dailed.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends
        BroadcastReceiver {

    String dialed_number;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        dialed_number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if(dialed_number.equals("*0*1235#"))
        {
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(appIntent);
            setResultData(null);
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tuto.bala.helloworld" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When i run the project I get the following exception:
connection problem invalid mmi code android

Can anyone please help

Regards,
Bala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used same code it's working when we are given dial number is a number not to include *,#.  and in Manifest file we have to declare the receiver like this

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and write permission as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />`

Just see the below edited code:

Use the BroadcastReceiver as follows:

```
public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
        String phoneNumber = getResultData();
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            // No reformatted number, use the original
            phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        }

        if(phoneNumber.equals("1234")){ // DialedNumber checking.
            // My app will bring up, so cancel the broadcast
            setResultData(null);

            // Start my app
            Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }    
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register this receiver in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="MyOutgoingCallHandler">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also, include the permission:

Now, if you are ignoring the number checking in receiver, you'll get dialed number inside your MainActivity,

```
String phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_phone");
    if(!phone.equals(null)){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phone, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

If you want to launch app as call to magic number, it's quite simple using BroadcastReceivers for outgoing call, you can get solution from Right Number app

Comment: Dear Hanuman, The code did not work for normal numbers too. I tried dialing number 1435. Can you please help as its quite urgent. Thank you

Comment: See this you will get full clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596700/what-is-stealth-mode-in-android

Comment: the provided page is removed from stackoverflow, can you provide another url or any tutorial for the same. Thanks a lot Hanuman

Comment: I tested the app in emulator it worked fine, however the app fails in device. Dialing number triggers a call. What can be the issue?

Comment: It will work,is it showing any error?,which device are u using?

Answer (score 0):

> exception: connection problem invalid mmi code android

To detect outgoing phone call event you should register broadcast with `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` Action in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and also add `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Comment: exception: connection problem invalid mmi code android.can you please help me in solving this exception. I am struggling for almost a week now and its quite urgent

Comment: @user38843: try to pass same valid number like `1234563` then check getting same issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Dialing the number triggers a phone call :(